# Hiding a delete button when you tap outside the view

Tags: ios, button

I have a delete button that shows up when I swipe left on a table view's row.

I want to be able to hide this button if the user taps anywhere else in the view. How do I do that? I tried putting a giant button on bottom of all views but the tap outside is not being detected by the button.

In the `viewDidLoad`, I added the view controller as a target:

```
[self.backgroundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And in the callback I just  have a message:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"BACKGROUND VIEW TOUCHED");
}
```

But when I tap outside in a general area, I do not see the message.

Comment: Any possibility that your UIButton is lying behind some other views? Cud you try giving different bgColor to your UITableView and all other view and check whether the button is outside of all views.

Comment: Thanks HRM. The view does lie behind all subviews including a tableview and a collection view. I thought that was the point?

Comment: You are welcome..Hope the issue fixed...:)

Comment: No actually it is not. What I was saying was that it is my understanding that the button *Should* lie beyond other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue as follows:

. Created a view TopView subclassed from UIView
. Changed class of my top level view to this class.
. Within my logic at the proper place, stored the subview that needs to be hidden in the top view

```
self.view.mySubview = subview;
```

. Overrode hitTest:withEvent in top view. Here I detect the tap *outside* that of the subview and hide the subview as required.

Comment: If you fixed your problem, I recommend you choose your own answer as the accepted answer.